# Subclass native Array in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, typescript

I'm trying to subclass of native Array so that I can add a method to it:

```
var a = new Array(0,1,2);  // => [0,1,2]

class MyArray extends Array<number> {
    someMethod(a: number) {
        return this[2] === a;
    }
}

var b = new MyArray(0,1,2);  // => Error.  Supplied parameters to do not match any signature of call target `constructor MyArray(): MyArray`
```

The [TypeScript wiki post](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#extending-expressions) announcing it's support in 1.6 doesn't shown an example of instantiation.

** **edit** **

The question was more like: is there a way to implement the subclass and retain the full functionality of the parent constructor which has a signature capable of dealing with instantiation by `new Array(0,1,2)`?

I understand you can implement your own constructor and that the JavaScript compiled from the TypeScript does not work.